# Move menu when the keyboard opens (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, keyboard

I have problems with my function "keyboardWillShown". So what I want is that my menu appears exactly above the keyboard when it opens. It works perfectly on Iphone 8 plus, 8, 7, 6. But when I run Iphone 11 on the simulator the result is as follows.

[Picture of how it looks in Iphone 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkDkV.png)

[Constrains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4MEB.png)

Here's my code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.keyboardConstrains.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
    })
}
```

Calling function

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShown(notification:)), name:  UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil )
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver( self,name:  UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the constraints according to the size of your screen

```
if self.view.height >= 800{ //For bigger screens (X ,11)
    self.keyboardConstrains.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height - 50
} else {
    self.keyboardConstrains.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
}
```

Comment: it sounds like a good solution, But when I do it I get error "Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'height". Do you know what it might be?

Comment: try using -> self.view.frame.size.height

Answer (score 0):

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
keyboardConstrains.constant = (keyboardSize?.height)! - (bottomPadding ?? 0)
```

It is because all notch iPhone(X, Xr, iPhone11 etc) have safe area in bottom as well so keyboard height calculating from Main view and you are setting "keyboardConstrains" from safe area that's why this space is coming. For removing this space you have to check if there is safe area in bottom than you have to minus bottom space from keyboard height.